# Long url is not being set in $_GET array

Tags: php, http-get

I have the following query string:

```
 [QUERY_STRING] => u=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.yahoo.com%2Fblogs%2Fsideshow%2Fman-fathered-30-kids-needs-break-child-support-140439765.html&t=%3Cp%20id=%22yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_287%22%3EAnd%20you%20thought%20Octomom%20had%20her%20hands%20full%E2%80%94a%20Tennessee%20man%20who%20has%20fathered%2030%20children%20is%20asking%20the%20courts%20for%20a%20break%20on%20child%20support.%3C/p%3E%0A%3Cp%20id=%22yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_286%22%3EDesmond%20Hatchett,%2033,%20of%20Knoxville%20has%20children%20with%2011%20different%20women,%20%3Ca%20href=%22http://wreg.com/2012/05/16/tn-man-fathers-30-kids-but-cant-support-any/%22%20target=%22_blank%22%3Ereports%20WREG-TV%3C/a%3E.%3C/p%3E%0A%3Cp%20id=%22yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_285%22%3EThe%20state%20already%20takes%20half%20his%20paycheck%20and%20divides%20it%20up,%20which%20doesn%27t%20amount%20to%20much%20when%20Hatchett%20is%20making%20only%20minimum%20wage.%20Some%20of%20the%20moms%20receive%20as%20little%20as%20$1.49%20a%20month.%20The%20oldest%20child%20is%2014%20years%20old.%3C/p%3E%0A%3Cp%20id=%22yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_284%22%3EHatchett%20explains%20how%20he%20reached%20such%20a%20critical%20mass:%20He%20had%20four%20kids%20in%20the%20same%20year.%20Twice.%3C/p%3E%0A%3Cp%20id=%22yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_283%22%3E%3Ca%20href=%22http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTZk1y8iaho%22%20target=%22_blank%22%20id=%22yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_308%22%3EBack%20in%202009%20when%20Hatchett%20%3C/a%3Ewas%20in%20court%20to%20answer%20charges%20that%20many%20of%20the%20mothers%20were%20not%20receiving%20child%20support,%20he%20had%2021%20children.%20At%20the%20time,%20he%20said%20he%20was%20not%20going%20to%20father%20any%20more%20kids,%20but%20he%20ended%20up%20having%20nine%20more%20in%20the%20past%20three%20years.%3C/p%3E%0A%3Cp%20id=%22yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_282%22%3EThe%20state%20cannot%20order%20Hatchett%20to%20stop%20making%20babies.%20He%20hasn%27t%20broken%20any%20laws,%20according%20to%20the%20report.%3C/p%3E
```

However the only thing in my $_GET array is the following:

```
 [u] => http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/sideshow/man-fathered-30-kids-needs-break-child-support-140439765.html
```

My get request is less than 2k characters and the server received the entire string so I have no idea what could be going on.

Comment: Tested on local server and everything came through fine into GET array.  Note that the ampersand following the portion you've listed will force the next part of the URL into a different element of the GET array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

print_r($_GET);

In my case, using the same query string i get this result:

```
Array
(
    [u] => http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/sideshow/man-fathered-30-kids-needs-break-child-support-140439765.html
    [t] => <p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_287">And you thought Octomom had her hands full—a Tennessee man who has fathered 30 children is asking the courts for a break on child support.</p>
<p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_286">Desmond Hatchett, 33, of Knoxville has children with 11 different women, <a href="http://wreg.com/2012/05/16/tn-man-fathers-30-kids-but-cant-support-any/" target="_blank">reports WREG-TV</a>.</p>
<p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_285">The state already takes half his paycheck and divides it up, which doesn't amount to much when Hatchett is making only minimum wage. Some of the moms receive as little as $1.49 a month. The oldest child is 14 years old.</p>
<p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_284">Hatchett explains how he reached such a critical mass: He had four kids in the same year. Twice.</p>
<p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_283"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTZk1y8iaho" target="_blank" id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_308">Back in 2009 when Hatchett </a>was in court to answer charges that many of the mothers were not receiving child support, he had 21 children. At the time, he said he was not going to father any more kids, but he ended up having nine more in the past three years.</p>
<p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_282">The state cannot order Hatchett to stop making babies. He hasn't broken any laws, according to the report.</p>
)
```

the second value is in there.

Maybe is the configuration of your php.

**- suhosin.get.max_name_length (Default: 64)**
Defines the maximum length of variable names for variables registered through the URL. For array variables this is the name in front of the indices.

**- suhosin.get.max_totalname_length (Default: 256)**
Defines the maximum length of the total variable name when registered through the URL. For array variables this includes all indices.

**- suhosin.get.max_value_length (Default: 512)**
Defines the maximum length of a variable that is registered through the URL.

Greatings.

Comment: I actually did print_r for the things I posted above. Maybe it is an issue with my webhost.

Comment: I guess that is what it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the query string you will se the cause of your problem.

```
.....140439765.html&t=%3Cp%20id=....
```

Take a close look at the `&` after the html extension.
You need to use [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) in whole url before passing it to your php script.

```
$link='http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/sideshow/man-fathered-30-kids-needs-break-child-support-140439765.html&t=<p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_287">And you thought Octomom had her hands fulla Tennessee man who has fathered 30 children is asking the courts for a break on child support.</p><p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_286">Desmond Hatchett, 33, of Knoxville has children with 11 different women, <a href="http://wreg.com/2012/05/16/tn-man-fathers-30-kids-but-cant-support-any/" target="_blank">reports WREG-TV</a>.</p><p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_285">The state already takes half his paycheck and divides it up, which doesn\'t amount to much when Hatchett is making only minimum wage. Some of the moms receive as little as .49 a month. The oldest child is 14 years old.</p><p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_284">Hatchett explains how he reached such a critical mass: He had four kids in the same year. Twice.</p><p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_283"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTZk1y8iaho" target="_blank" id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_308">Back in 2009 when Hatchett </a>was in court to answer charges that many of the mothers were not receiving child support, he had 21 children. At the time, he said he was not going to father any more kids, but he ended up having nine more in the past three years.</p><p id="yui_3_4_0_22_1337372504263_282">The state cannot order Hatchett to stop making babies. He hasn\'t broken any laws, according to the report.</p>';
echo '<a href="script.php?u=' . urlencode($link) . '">The link title</a>'
```

That should work.